# Слайдер с position fixed

Tags: html, css, slider, swiper, fixed

У меня следующая проблема. Мне необходимо создать слайдер, который при прокрутке страницы закрепляется сверху экрана. Как на примере скрина.
[image: Скрин]

Я не прошу вас реализовать функционал в плане добавления position fixed при прокрутке, это я уже сделал с помощью jquery. Если я задаю position: fixed wrapper, самому слайдеру или родительскому контейнеру fixed растягивает слайдер на всю ширину экрана не обращая внимания на контейнер.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользуюсь библиотекой swiper, если это имеет какое-то значение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А если в контейнер, который растянут на ширину экрана, засунуть еще один контейнер, который будет нужной ширины, а уже в него засунуть слайдер?

Comment: я уже пробовал делать манипуляции с контейнером, такое ощущение, что с position fixed слайдер игнорирует все контейнеры в том числе overflow hidden

Comment: Замените `position: fixed` на что-то другое лучше...